# Knockout templates: afterRender triggered twice because name/data are coupled observables

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js

I'm having trouble getting afterRender to trigger exactly once. I'm seeing that afterRender is triggered twice because I have two observables in my template binding that update at the same time:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: template.name(), data: template.data, if: template.data, afterRender: doSomeStuff }">
</div>
```

This is because an update to `name` triggers an update to `data` since it is a computed observable whose value depends on name:

```
this.data = ko.computed({
    var viewName = this.name();
    switch (viewName) {
        case "a":
            return this.modelA();
        case "b":
            return this.modelB();
        case "c":
            return this.modelC();
        default:
            return null;
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is log the time the template is rendered. I'm also concerned about potential performance implications of rendering twice - are those DOM elements within the template being created twice every single time `name` changes?

It *is* possible for `data` to change (e.g. the modelA, modelB or modelC object changes) without `name` changing and I do want `data` changes to trigger afterRender if it is changed by itself. Ideally, I would be able to couple the name-data update to trigger `afterRender` once but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this?

- I looked into throttle extenders but those wouldn't prevent the
  template binding from being triggered twice
- `deferEvaluation` on the
  `data` computed observable does not appear to cause the template
  binding to pick up the new object when `template.name` changes (not
  sure if this is because the template binding is not actually
  reevaluating `data` when `template.name` changes), and should still trigger the template binding twice.

I'm thinking about getting rid of the data object completely and in each HTML template, attaching a `with` binding directly to modelA, modelB, and modelC, but then I wouldn't get those afterRender updates if the data changes.

Edit: I am using KO 2.2.1, and realized that the template name can't be observable (until 2.3.0), hence the parentheses after template.name. So my original assumption that this afterRender is happening twice because name is an observable too must be incorrect?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option at this time, but I will keep that in mind as a future solution if I can't find something that works now. Are you referring to this improvement: "Bindings on a given element now update independently" (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/10/08/knockout-3-0-release-candidate-available/)?

Comment: Actually Knockout 3.0 won't help in this case because it's a single binding, `template`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings are updated using a computed observable that tracks changes to any dependencies. Your situation is like this: computed C (`template` binding) is dependent on computed B (`data`) and observable A (`name`), and computed B is dependent on observable A. When A changes, it updates B and C. And when B updates, it also updates C. So that's why C gets two updates.

For reference, here's your example in jsFiddle showing two updates: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/DnY9V/

#### Throttle extender

Knockout's throttle extender is the only built-in way to prevent multiple updates. You can create a custom binding that wraps the template binding to run the update in a throttled computed observable.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.throttledTemplate = {
    init: function(element) {
        var args = arguments, self = this,
            result = ko.bindingHandlers.template.init.apply(this, arguments);
        ko.computed(function() {
            ko.bindingHandlers.template.update.apply(self, args);
        }, null, {disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element}).extend({throttle:1});

        return result;
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/j5D6p/

#### Deferred Updates plugin

Alternatively, you can use my Deferred Updates plugin that prevents all duplicate updates to computed observables: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-deferred-updates

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/UXYJx/

Comment: I just updated my jsFiddle examples to use 2.2.1 instead of 3.0.0 to show that they still apply.